# Cascading three Telerik MVC Comboboxes, third combobox not getting refreshed

Tags: jquery, telerik-combobox

I am using three Telerik MVC comboboxes which I want to cascade on change. When the user changes the first combobox, the options of second combobox should change through ajax call, and because the second combobox changes, the third combobox options should change too. I hooked up the onChange event on first and second combobox to fire ajax get. When I change first combobox, the onchange event is fired correctly and the values of the second combobox gets refreshed. But although the second combobox options have now being changed, the onchange event for the second combobox does not fire until I tab into the second combobox and again tab out of it. Why the second combobox onchange event doesn't fire when I change its options through JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a solution at

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/combobox/stranger-behavior-in-cascading-three-dropdownlist.aspx

The basic thing is that selecting item from javascript does not fire onchange() event. So we need to trigger it manually.